# runtime error for leetcode problem 154 : reorder list

Tags: c++, vector, linked-list

https://leetcode.com/problems/reorder-list/

> this is my codes 
>   logic

```
 1) taking care of edge cases when 0,1,2 elements in list
 2) storing node addresses in vector addr
 3) inserting last nodes after 1st nodes one by one i.e 1-2-3 should become 1-3-2
```

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
 * };
 */
#define Node ListNode
class Solution {
public:
    void reorderList(ListNode* head) 
    {
        if(head == nullptr || head->next == nullptr || head->next->next == nullptr)
        {
            return;
        }

        // copy to vector
        vector <Node*> addr;
        Node *temp = head;
        while(temp != nullptr)
        {
            addr.push_back(temp);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        int n = addr.size();
        Node *ins = addr[--n];
        temp = head;

        while(temp != ins)
        {
            // insert after temp
            ins->next = temp->next;
            temp->next = ins;
            if((--n) != 0)
                ins = addr[n];
            temp = temp->next->next;
        }
        temp->next = nullptr;
    }
};
```

> this is my output

Line 924: Char 34: runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x603000000010 overflowed to 0x603000000008 (stl_vector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/bits/stl_vector.h:933:34

> random edits made and code worked altho i still dunno why the above code is not working!

```
class Solution {
public:
        void reorderList(Node* head) 
    {
        if(head == nullptr || head->next == nullptr || head->next->next == nullptr)
        {
            return;
        }

        // copy to vector
        vector <Node*> addr;
        Node *temp = head;
        while(temp != nullptr)
        {
            addr.push_back(temp);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        int n = addr.size();
        Node *ins = addr[--n];
        temp = head;

        while(temp != ins && temp->next != ins)
        {
            // insert after temp
            ins->next = temp->next;
            temp->next = ins;
            ins = addr[--n];
            temp = temp->next->next;
        }
        if(temp->next == ins)
        {
            ins->next = nullptr;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->next = nullptr;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: It doesn't crash when you run it locally? Do this "leetcode" site provide the input given when a crash happens? If it does, have you tried that data to run locally, and it still doesn't crash? When you build, enable verbose warnings, do you get any warnings? Then treat them as errors and fix them. Does fixing the warnings help?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah i was going to do that but before that i just made some changes (refer edit above) and it worked on leetcode !

Comment: what is your question? You have broken code and you have fixed code, so what is the problem?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but i will still try to diagnose the problem i was getting before do let me know if u find it by any chance :D

Comment: I have voted to close since, at this time, there does not seem to be a question left.

Comment: This is what debuggers are for. They're good at identifying the precise problem you're having.

Comment: @idclev463035818 problem is i still dunno why i am getting the error in the first code

Comment: There's a lot of really strange code going on here, like how all that work with `n` and finding the end of the array to pull out a pointer *you just put in there* called `temp`.

Comment: @einpoklum i still dunno why the problem occured in the first place

Comment: `addr[--n]` in a loop is asking for trouble. You're liable to drive `n` negative and crash. The `#define Node ListNode` part is also extremely suspect. C++ has aliasing features far better than `#define`.

Comment: @tadman its not in a loop its in an if statement

Comment: It's literally inside a `while`. If your structure is badly linked `while(temp != ins && temp->next != ins)` will drive `n` negative.

Comment: @tadman oh i see, you are referring to the editted code. but that works..n never becomes less than n/2

Comment: "Works" in C++ doesn't mean it's not full of undefined behaviour or bugs.

Comment: @tadman i see. subtle nuances. so what would the correct way of writing it look like?

Comment: These so-called "leet code" type challenges don't really show you how C++ works in production code, but instead this hacked up, half-assed C++ that honestly misses the point. This should be done with a proper class that follows RAII rules to clean itself up properly. [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) will give your code a failing grade due to all the leaks.

Comment: @dagwood: Then please post a complete program which triggers an error.

Comment: @einpoklum the entire program is hidden from me. Only the function is left to code.